# What is the difference and why both need in NSDate: timeIntervalSince1970 and timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate?

Tags: ios, nsdate

There is two `NSDate` method, and I do not know when, which to use. Any idea?

```
NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: <#NSTimeInterval#>) //reference date is 1970.01.01
NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: <#NSTimeInterval#>) //reference date is 2001.01.01
```

Which one do you prefer to use, is it any compatibility concern, I mean i.e. `CloudKit` interpret date referring to 1970. Does oher system use different reference date, is this the goal to have two method for same purpose?

Comment: Did you read the docs for the two methods? What confusion do you have?

Comment: FYI - there are 4 `timeIntervalSinceXXX` methods, not just the two in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the various `NSDate timeIntervalSinceXXX` methods return the number of seconds since some specific epoch. You choose one based on how the resulting time interval needs to be used.

If you are sending the time interval to some Unix based server, it is probably best to use `timeIntervalSince1970` since times in Unix are based on January 1, 1970.

If the time interval will be used to create an `NSDate` in iOS or OS X, use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`.

Simply look at how the time interval will be used to know which method is appropriate for your need.